# JPanels in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, mixing

I have a problem with Java JPanels. I would like to put 2 JPanels with different layouts into one JPanel which is also has a layout. Is it even possible to make it work?

```
    BibP()
setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1)); //The big JPanel
add(new A(), new FlowLayout(4));
add(new B(), new GridLayout(7,2));
```

Both A and B are classes extends as JPanels and no matter what I changed or commented B is always appears in 1 row.
I have 4 elements added to A and 14 to B (JLabels and JTextAreas) and there is not much code in them only the adds and some calculation.

The problem might be in the JFrame where I am trying to put the big JPanel.

```
    JFrame.this.add(new BigP(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Edit:

```
    public class BigP extends JPanel{
//Labels and TextAres

public class A extends JPanel{
    public A(){
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, -50, 0, 0));
        //get date and add to textareas
        //add the label and textareas
}
}

public class B extends JPanel{
    public B (){
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, -50, 0, 0));
        setBackground(Color.red);
        //colum longs for text areas less then 5
        //add labels and textareas
    }
}

public BigP(){
    setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
    setBorder(new EmptyBorder(3,-160,0,0));

    add(new A(), new FlowLayout(4));
    add(new B(), new GridLayout(7,2));
}
}
```

Thanks for helping.

After a few tries:

If I used this:

```
    add(new B(), new GridLayout(7,2));
```

I get this in B when I printlned the layout:

java.awt.FlowLayout[hgap=5,vgap=5,align=center]

If I set the Layout in B:

```
    setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 2));
```

The information is correct:

java.awt.GridLayout[hgap=0,vgap=0,rows=7,cols=2]

But there is only 2 JTextAreas vissible where should be 14 elements.

Comment: The code seems to be missing critical parts.  If I complete it mentally, then everything looks fine.  Can you please make sure you entered **exactly** what you have.  Obviously there is a problem with it.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it even possible to make it work?

Yes, it's commonly know as compound layouts.

The problem you have is you are trying to supply the `Layout`s as constraints to the current containers layout manager (which in your case, your lucky it wasn't expecting any)...

Instead, supply the layout manager directly to the child panels...something like...

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1)); //The big JPanel

JPanel a = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(4));
JPanel b = new JPanel(new GridLayout(7,2));
add(a);
add(b);
```

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details...

**Update with example**

Simple runnable example, using labels as place holders.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class ExampleLayout {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ExampleLayout();
  }

  public ExampleLayout() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        JPanel mainPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 1));
        mainPane.add(new APanel());
        mainPane.add(new BPanel());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  public class APanel extends JPanel {

    public APanel() {
      setLayout(new FlowLayout(4));
      for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
        add(new JLabel(Integer.toString(index)));
      }
      setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
    }

  }

  public class BPanel extends JPanel {

    public BPanel() {
      setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 2));
      for (int index = 0; index < 14; index++) {
        add(new JLabel(Integer.toString(index)));
      }
      setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));
    }

  }

}
```

This `setBorder(new EmptyBorder(3,-160,0,0));` also looks wrong.  `EmptyBorder` should NEVER have negative values

Comment: Its the same, B is still appears in 1 row. I typed this: A a = new A(); add(a, new GridLayout(7,2)); If I set the layout in A I only get 2 TextAreas back and not the 14 elements that I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Is it even possible to make it work?
```

Yes it is possible to do this. In the following line

```
JFrame.this.add(new BigP(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I would suggest do

```
mainFrame.getContentPane.add(new BigP());
```

and set the layout of your mainFrame before this

```
mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
```

Comment: Interesting.  `JFrame` uses `BorderLayout` by default.  If you don't supply a position constraint to the layout, it uses `Center` by default, so `JFrame.this.add(new BigP(),BorderLayout.CENTER);` and `mainFrame.getContentPane.add(new BigP());` would be the same thing...until you changed the layout manager ;)

Comment: I think not the JFrame is the problem beacuse if I comment like this:
        
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(3,-160,0,0));
        
        //add(new A(), new FlowLayout(4));
        add(new B(), new GridLayout(7,2));    

B still appears in one row.